Visual Studio shows 'No package found" with Nexus Repository Manager OSS NuGet proxy configuration
I have installed Nexus 3.70.02-01 Repository Manager OSS on Ubuntu 22.04 and configured Nginx as a reverse proxy. I then accessed Nexus via the web, added a NuGet proxy, and configured the remote storage with the following URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Everything seems correct, but when I try to download a package from Visual Studio through the NuGet proxy, it displays "No package found". Please note that from the Nexus server, I can successfully access the URL https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
Could you please assist me?
I try to download nuget pacakges throught the proxy nuget but always i have no package found


Did you complete the post-installation checklist. 2. Did you configure Visual Studio to point to the repository?  3. On the computer with Visual Studio, please post the result of visiting the repository URL manually in the browser (if a proxy is necessary for this request, use the same proxy settings Visual Studio is using)?


Which are you using: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?
